# How can I pass an object from Swift to Javascript?

Tags: ios, angularjs, swift

I am considering using angular.js in a uiwebview for a certain part of my iOS app that needs a special layout that is easiest to do with html. I will need to pass some objects from Swift to javascript to be handled by angular. How can I do that?